# In pycharm .py file is run in python console mode

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

When I ran my program in pycharm that time my .py file output came in  python console mode and also  did not see  the "Run" option in below(before debug).Please help me to set "Run" option.So I can execute my program using "Run" option.Attaching screen shot.

current is :[image]

[image]

Expected:

[image]

Comment: Easiest way is to right click on the editor frame and select ''Run" from the context menu.

Comment: I tried, but still it is running in python console